# Why is my conky shown above other windows?

Tags: window, conky

My `conky` is running in the foreground =(

Does anybody know how to fix it?
I am running trusty tahir.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your .conkyrc file.

Comment: This question should be removed because it was never updated with the needed information. In its current state it's a distraction as a search result.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure without seeing your `~/.conkyrc` file, but yours probably includes these lines:

```
own_window_type normal
own_window_hints undecorated,above,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
```

The details might be different but you nee to change `above` to `below` and the set the window type to `desktop`:

```
own_window_type desktop
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
```

Comment: hmm that doesn't work i discovered that if i start cronky automatic and not manually the problem will occur probably because of compiz so i think it will be fixed if i set that cronky starts 5 seconds later =) alone i don't know how to do that

Comment: @user214128 please [edit] your question and show us your `.conkyrc` file as I asked in my previous comment. The details will depend on your settings. Also explain how you're starting conky.